# Trait object cannot be shared between threads safely

Tags: rust, trait-objects

When I am writing a zookeeper client in RUST.

code like this :

```
pub trait ZookeeperHandler {
    fn on_child_change(&self, path : &str, value : &String);
    fn on_valude_change(&self, path : &str, value: String);
    fn reload_all_child(&self, path : &str, children : HashMap<String, String>);
}

pub struct WatchNode  {
    path : String,
    node_type: i32,
    handler : Box<dyn ZookeeperHandler>,
}

pub struct WatchNodeManager {
    watch_nodes : HashMap<String, WatchNode>,
}

impl  WatchNodeManager  {
    //do something
}

pub struct ZKProxy {
    init : bool,
    address: String,
    zk : Option<ZooKeeper>,
    watch_nodes : WatchNodeManager,
}

lazy_static! {
    pub static ref ZK_PROXY : Box<ZKProxy> = Box::new(ZKProxy::new(String::from("127.0.0.1:2081")));
}
```

This fails with the following message:

```
   |
59 | / lazy_static! {
60 | |     pub static ref ZK_PROXY : Box<ZKProxy> = Box::new(ZKProxy::new(String::from("127.0.0.1:2081")));
61 | | }
   | |_^ `(dyn ZookeeperHandler + 'static)` cannot be shared between threads safely
   |
```

As a beginner of RUST, I can't figure out what this error means and how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As global statics can be accessed by multiple threads at the same time, they have to be thread safe. Objects can have the auto-trait `Sync` that indicates that they are thread-safe.

Unless something prevents that, all types are `Send + Sync`. In your case, though, your type contains a `Box<dyn Zookeeper>`, which is neither `Send` nor `Sync`, because it could be anything that is `dyn Zookeeper`. You need to tell Rust that this only accepts `Sync` objects:

```rust
pub struct WatchNode {
    path: String,
    node_type: i32,
    handler: Box<dyn ZookeeperHandler + Sync>,
}
```

Comment: If `Box<dyn ZookeeperHandler>` was a type from another crate that you can't modify (i.e. `Display<SPIInterfaceNoCS<Spi, OutputPin>, ST7789, OutputPin>`), is `Mutex` a good option?

Comment: @MartinSchaer Yes, I would say so. [`std::sync::Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) converts a objects that are only `Send` to objects that are `Send+Sync`. That said, your `SPIInterfaceNoCS` indicates that this is actually an embedded `no-std` project. Be aware that there is no platform independent way of implementing a mutex, so in many cases, a `no-std` platform does not **have** a mutex. And many `no-std` mutexes (such as the one based on [`critical_section`](https://docs.rs/critical-section/latest/critical_section/)) work a little different.